# MapProxy as authentication tool?

Tags: authentication, mapproxy

I have some OGC WMS services made in MapServer. Now, I want to restrict access to data for some users by, for example, username, number of requests, or bbox.

Can this be done using MapProxy?

I read the [documentation](https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/auth.html) and there were mentioned WSGI middleware and MapProxy Authorization API as ways to accomplish this, but I am having trouble implementing this.

I am using MapProxy inside a docker container.

Comment: It would be useful to know what you have actually tried for both the authentication and authorization and what isn't working as expected.  As Authentication and Authorization are separate functions, it might be you have two  questions...  As to your general question as to whether it should be possible, the documentation would suggest yes.